# Should I approve edits on off-topic questions or answers to poor or off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

Should edits to off-topic or low quality questions (such as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355851/question-about-php-file-view-and-downloading)) be approved if they do nothing to improve the topicality or quality of the question itself?

Comment: Related on MSE: [Requesting a "stop polishing turds" edit suggestion reject reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260302)

Answer (score 2):

No. Especially if it's an older question that has fallen off the homepage - all you'll be doing is bumping up a question that doesn't belong or is already closed. If the edit doesn't fix the actual problems with the post, there's no reason to approve it.

Comment: I do tend to approve edits to recent, not-yet-closed questions if they improve legibility – so close voters can more easily see that the post isn't just low quality but actually off topic.